# Return type of an included file

Tags: php, eclipse

Suppose I have a file called `routes.php` containing routes for my webapp:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing;

$routes = new Routing\RouteCollection();
// Add routes here

return $routes;
```

This file is then included in my front controller as follows:

```
$routes = include 'routes.php';
```

Clearly this `$routes` object is of type `RouteCollection`. However, Eclipse doesn't seem to be aware of this, and as such I can't view the the object's methods when I start typing `$routes->` which makes it difficult to know what methods and parameters are available to me.

Is there any way for me to hint at the return type of my `routes.php` file? I've tried adding an annotation `@return \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection` at the top of the routes file, but this doesn't seem to make any difference.

I'm using Eclipse 4.2 with the Aptana Studio 3 plugin. If this is a limitation specific to Aptana, would PDT handle this differently?

Comment: why not check  `var_dump( include 'routes.php');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return types for files are not specified in PHPDoc, so you will have to define the type where you include it:

```
/* @var $routes \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection */
$routes = include 'routes.php';
```

Depending on the IDE it is `/** @var` (i.e. Zend Studio, Eclipse PDT) or `/* @var` (i.e. Aptana, NetBeans)

Comment: That looks exactly like what I need. It just doesn't seem to work in Aptana. Will have to try it in PDT and see if it works there...

Comment: It looks like the `@var` annotation in Aptana only works in single-asterisk comments, not double-asterisk comments. Please replace the double-asterisk comment with a single-asterisk comment and I'll accept your answer. ie:

`/* @var $routes \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection */`